# scroll event in useEffect doesn't reinitialize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener

so i have a Screen Component that fetches some data based on a category, the thing is when i change the category the cb function that scroll event uses doesn't refreshes, it uses the old category.

const categoryFromParams = safePah(false, ['match', 'params', 'category'], props);

```
const [indexs, setIndexs] = useState({
    firstIndex: 0,
    lastIndex: 9
});


const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

const handleScroll = (category, test) => () => {

    test.firstIndex = test.lastIndex;
    test.lastIndex = test.lastIndex + 9;

    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = document.documentElement;

    if (clientHeight + scrollTop >= scrollHeight - 5) {

        if (!loading) {
            setLoading(true);

            getFeedCategory({
                category,
                ...test
            }).then(response => {
                const feed = safePah([], ['data'], response);
                setLoading(false);

                setFeed(prevState => [...prevState, ...feed])
            })

        }
    }
}


    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        setFeed([]);
        getFeedCategory({ category: categoryFromParams, ...indexs }).then(response => {
            const feed = safePah([], ['data'], response);
            setLoading(false);

            setFeed(prevState => [...prevState, ...feed])
        });

        const test = {
            firstIndex: 9,
            lastIndex: 18
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000))

        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll',  debounce(handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000))

    }, [categoryFromParams])
```

idk how to change the behavior of this, that when a category is change my eventListner refreshes.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is, but can you try to separate `debounce(handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000)` to a single variable inside useEffect ?

Comment: Ah, Can I see your `debounce` function? I only useDebounce in this [link](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/)

Comment: @dshung1997 its the debounce from lodash

Comment: @dshung1997 the problem is that when const categoryFromParams = safePath(false, ['match', 'params', 'category'], props); changes, the function inside addEventListener doesn't use the new categoryFromParams

Comment: I think the debounce from lodash doesn't work in this context. And I just checked, the useDebounce above is not what you want. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-throttle-cg2x0?file=/src/App.tsx) is an example of the useDebounce that I use. I was inspired by [this post](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf)

Comment: OK. The comment above doesn't really solve the problem. I guess you tried `window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000)` (remove debounce) and you still got the issue, right?

Comment: @dshung1997 yeah, i need that debounce because i don't what to fetch multiple times in a row

Comment: Have you tried to use `debounce(handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000)` as a separate variable? 

I'm not sure but I suspect this `return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll',  debounce(handleScroll(categoryFromParams, test), 1000))` will remove the listener

Comment: *not remove, I mean. Sorry for this